# Dynamic tables based on variable in foreach container

Tags: ssis

I'm creating my dimensions but I have a company that is divided in 10 groups, theses groups all have the same tables. I need to create a DW spanning all 10 groups.

I have created a Sql Task that selects all 10 groups. This sql task points to a foreach loop container that takes the input and puts it into a variable. Now I have tested this with a script task, but I want to go a step further. I want to define a dataflow tasks in my foreach container and fill my dimensions with data depending on my variable

I want something like this in my dataflow

```
select value from @variable$tablename
```

How can i select my data based on what is in my variable? My variable is in the User namespace, User::group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by creating a script task that concatenates the query in a string. Store this string into a variable and read from this variable in your data flow.
more information can be found here http://www.select-sql.com/mssql/how-to-use-a-variable-inside-sql-in-ssis-data-flow-tasks.html